# Django Model M2M Relationship to 2 other models from the same model

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, relationship

Here in my problem, I have a User model, in which a user (login) can be from the “Supplier” company or from “Customer” company.

It is a M2M relationship for both sets of tables: User-Customer and User-Supplier.

Can I link them this way:

`company = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, Supplier, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Users')`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Ndu.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't do that.**

A better approach will be if you use a `Company` model with a type of `Supplier` and `Customer` you can create an enum for this because you are using the same fields in both of your models so its good to have a type in a single model.

[How to make enum in model with TextChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

```
Company:
     name
     address
     contact name
     type
```

then in your `User` model

```
company = models.ManyToManyField(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Users')
```

make more sense this way.

Comment: What an easier way!!! Why I didn't see it before!!! ..thanks :)